# get extra field value in join table asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i have tables mapped to many to many relationship and in join table i have extra field Unit (integer), checked (boolean)
so any one would help me read Unit value. .

Controller:-

```
 // GET: PatientFees/Edit/5
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

       ServiceFeeViewModel SFVM = new ServiceFeeViewModel();
        var St = _context.PatientFees.Include(s => s.PatientService).ThenInclude(e => e.Services).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(m => m.PatientID == id);
        var AllServices = _context.Services.Select(vm => new ServiceChecklistItems()
        {

            ServiceID = vm.ServiceID,
            Procedure = vm.Procedure,
            Amount = vm.Amount,
            Unit = ??,
            IsChecked = vm.PatientService.Any(x => x.PatientID == St.PatientID) ? true : false
        }).ToList();

        SFVM.PatientID = St.PatientID;
        SFVM.EstimateAmount = St.EstimateAmount;
        SFVM.Discount = St.Discount;
        SFVM.AmountToPay = St.AmountToPay;
        SFVM.AvailableServices = AllServices;

        return View(SFVM);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
 public class ServiceFeeViewModel{
    [Key ]       
    public int PatientID { get; set; }        
    public int EstimateAmount { get; set; }       
    public int Discount { get; set; }        
    public int AmountToPay { get; set; }

    public List<ServiceChecklistItems> AvailableServices { get; set; }
}
```

ChecklistItems:-

```
public class ServiceChecklistItems
{    
    [Key]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string Procedure { get; set; }        
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

the Three Connected Models

```
public class PatientFees
{
    [Key]               
    public int PatientID { get; set; }        
    public int EstimateAmount { get; set; }       
    public int Discount { get; set; }        
    public int AmountToPay { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public List<PatientService> PatientService { get; set; }

}

public class PatientService
{             

    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public PatientFees  PatientFees   { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public Services  Services { get; set; }   

    public int Unit { get; set; }

}

public class Services
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string Procedure { get; set; }        
    public int Amount { get; set; }        
    public DateTime   TimeFrame { get; set; }

    public List<PatientService> PatientService { get; set; }
}
```

patient service is the join table and have extra field Unit so i want when getting checked items to read also it's unit.

Comment: Share us model defination and the complete code related with `vm.StudentDepartment.Any(x => x.Departmentid == St.Studentid) ? true : false`. I am wondering what the business logic for `x.Departmentid == St.Studentid`.

Comment: I edited and added the full models and edit controller..

Comment: Which `PatientService.Unit` value you need? For `vm` which is a `Service`, a `Service` object has many `PatientService`. While one of `PatientService.Unit` you need? Max, min or sum?

Comment: as you can see Unit and Ischecked feilds are only in checklist items not in vm which is service , so when reading ischecked i used vm.PatientService.Any(x => x.PatientID == St.PatientID) ? true : false i want also for Unit

Comment: Does `ServiceChecklistItems` a model in `DbContext`? Do you mean query `ServiceChecklistItems.Unit` based on `ServiceID`?

Comment: ServiceChecklistitems is not amodel in dbcontext , yes i want servicechecklistitems.unit from PatientService.unit based on PatientID

Comment: For `PatientService`, it will have many `PatientService` with the same `PatientID `, which value do you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184986/discussion-between-tao-zhou-and-zakaria-abdalla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from discusstion:

```
var AllServices = _context.Services.Select(vm => new ServiceChecklistItems()
{

    ServiceID = vm.ServiceID,
    Procedure = vm.Procedure,
    Amount = vm.Amount,
    Unit = vm.PatientService.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PatientID == St.PatientID).Unit,
    IsChecked = vm.PatientService.Any(x => x.PatientID == St.PatientID) ? true : false
}).ToList();
```

also this one

```
 Unit = vm.PatientService.Where(x => x.PatientID == St.PatientID)
                .Select(x => x.Unit)
                .FirstOrDefault(),
```